# Google map framework error

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have added google map framework but I have got following error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMutablePath", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController+ProjSwizzles.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSPolygon", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_GMSPolygon_$_ZSwizzles in GMSPolygon+ZSwizzles.o
      objc-class-ref in ViewController+ProjSwizzles.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMapView", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_GMSMapView_$_Swizzles in GMSMapView+Swizzles.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

please check your `Frameworks`

```
AVFoundation.framework
CoreData.framework
CoreLocation.framework
CoreText.framework
GLKit.framework
ImageIO.framework
libc++.dylib
libicucore.dylib
libz.dylib
OpenGLES.framework
QuartzCore.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
```

Comment: please select architectures in standard architectures